# reverse engineer bootstrap customization

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

When i started using bootstrap, I put in a bunch of colors and fonts into their Customize page, then downloaded what ends up being compiled css (from the less).

i've since lost whatever changes i put in there, and they seem to be spread throughout the code.  Since it doesn't actually include the less customizations in the download, there doesn't appear to be a way to get the values i changed back out (to upgrade)

is there a utility out there that pulls the custom colors, fonts, sizes, etc out of bootstrap.css so i can reapply on a new version of bs?  or better yet re-generate the less so i can keep it separate and compile new bs.css files as they bump versions

Comment: I don't know of any way to reverse-engineer custom settings from Bootstrap's resulting CSS. You can prevent having to re-specify custom settings each time Bootstrap updates, though. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13809895/how-can-i-customize-twitter-bootstraps-css-using-lesscss-variables for details.