# Twitter Bootstrap + Less: setup

Tags: css, twitter, twitter-bootstrap, less, font-awesome

How to setup Twitter Bootstrap with Less? I downloaded from http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/
 the Twitter Bootstrap library and in the CSS folder are 4 files:

```
bootstrap.css
bootstrap.min.css
bootstrap-responsive.css
bootstrap-responsive.min.css
```

Then I decided to use LESS. So I went to GitHub - https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap where in the root is the folder called `less`. This folder contains 42 *.less files. I opened the `bootstrap.less` file and there there are included all the *.less files, but I don't see there the "responsive" less file.

And the second thing - I have to download all those 42 files and included them into into one file (bootstrap.less)?

Isn't there any better way to install **Twitter Bootstrap + Less (+ Font-Awesome)**
?

Comment: Do you want to use a custom build of bootstrap or you want to include the bootstrap.less file in your application?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/13809895/1430996 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/17623811/1430996 for details on how to compile the LESS code into the CSS template the browser will need.

Answer (score 0):

**To answer the second question**
There is a `less/responsive.less` file which contains the responsive code.

**To answer the first question**
I don't think it is a good idea to include the less files in your application as the less file parsing will consume client resources and it will effect the performance of your application.

If you want to do a custom build of bootstrap, you can use the [customize](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html) option from the bootstrap site.

If you want to make more customized build always you can clone the git repository and build it using a less tool like [Crunch!](http://crunchapp.net/) as given [here](http://bootstrap.lesscss.ru/less.html).

Answer (score 0):

There's also a CDN version here, complete with Twitter Bootstrap + Font Awesome:
http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/?v=01042013155511#tab_fontawesome

Answer (score 0):

We have a startup zip when we want to use less / bootstrap / boilerplate

You can download it from -> http://rhino.welcomweb.se/html-less-bootstrap.zip