# How can I customize the CSS generated by LESS to include Font Awesome?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, font-awesome

I want to customize [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)'s CSS by layering in [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) as a replacement for [Bootstrap's default Glyphicons](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#icons).

**How can I customize the CSS generated by LESS to include Font Awesome in a way that won't break if I update the core Bootstrap files?** Note: [Font Awesome suggests altering the core Bootstrap 'bootstrap.less' file](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/#custom-less) to replace `@import "sprites.less";` with `@import "path/to/font-awesome/less/font-awesome.less";`, *but this change would get overwritten if the Boostrap core were to be replaced* (by a version upgrade, for example).

Similar to my earlier question ("[How can I customize Twitter Bootstrap's CSS using LESSCSS variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13809895/1430996)"), we can assume I have this file structure:

```
/html
    /bootstrap
       ...etc...
       /js
       /less
    /Font-Awesome
       /css
       /font
       /less
       ...etc...
    /MyApp
       ...etc...
       /common_files
          /less
             style.less
```

Comment: I didn't sponsor the bounty--@DourHighArch sponsored it 10 days after I asked/answered (PS--thanks DHA!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following the pattern suggested in [Font Awesome's "getting started" section](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/#custom-less), edit the `MyApp/common_files/less/style.less` file to

1. import the `font-awesome/less/font-awesome.less` file, then
2. define the LESS variable '@fa-font-path' (for Font Awesome 4+) or '@FontAwesomePath' (for Font Awesome < 4)

So, given the directory structure in the question:

```
@import "../../../bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less";
@import "../../../bootstrap/less/responsive.less";
/* include the Font Awesome CSS */
@import "../../../Font-Awesome/less/font-awesome.less";

/* define path to Font Awesome 4's font folder*/
@fa-font-path:   "../../../Font-Awesome/fonts";
```

Or

```
/* or define path to Font Awesome 3's font folder*/
@FontAwesomePath:   "../../../Font-Awesome/font";
```

Comment: eum why ask the question with a bounty and reply to it 2 min after ?

Comment: @PatsyIssa: I didn't sponsor the bounty--@DourHighArch sponsored it 10 days after I asked/answered (PS--thanks DHA!)

Comment: @Patsy, I just reviewed a few dozen useless edits, and Jeromy made a series of great edits. These points will push him over the threshold to not need me to review his edits. Also, answering one's own question is good as well.

Comment: @DourHighArch by all means mate, was just curious